# URL rewriting messing with facebook likes and tweets count

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, url, overrides, social-buttons

I have added the Google +1, Facebook like and Twitter buttons to the products page.

The problem is when 2 or more products are created with the same name, magento creates the url-key from the name while appending its id.
Now each time the `Catalog URL Rewrites` index is run the url-key changes and instead of appending the id, it appends `id + 1`, and if that URL already exists, it appends `id + 1 + 1` etc... And each time it increments.

So, since the URL changed, and even though a 301 Redirect was created, Facebook wouldn't merge the like count, nor does twitter. Is there a settings somewhere, to stop Magento from keep changing the product URL on each Rewrite? Or is there nothing I can do about this?

Answer (score 1):

Are id+1 and id+1+1 the same product? If so why don't you just edit a product to keep the URL the same? You can change the URL if needed and create a rewrite if needed. Also,make sure you have canonical tags.